# Can't access php file from other domain

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I written a android mobile application in JQuery Mobile and PhoneGap in Eclipse. In the application I am calling a jquery ajax to load list of data from other domain.

My jquery ajax call code is:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: WEBSERVICE_URL,
            async: false,
            data: dataString,
            dataType: 'json',
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data) {
                loginData = new Object(data);
                hideActivityIndigator();
                if(loginData.success == "true"){
                    $.mobile.changePage("#selectionScreen", "slide", false, true);
                } else {
                    $("#message_ajax").html("Invalid UserName/Password.");
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
                hideActivityIndigator();
            }
        });
```

The variable "WEBSERVICE_URL" has a other domain php service url.
On executing above code on "pageview" event I am getting following error

```
Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
```

Any solution is there to access service from other domain in JQuery Mobile + PhoneGap...?

Comment: You can't post to cross-domain in JS as far as i remember :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Phonegap/Cordova you should be able to call cross-domain web-services.. are you using an emulator or a phone?

As for emulator I would recommend Ripple, you can add it as a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc) or Download the [standalone version](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple)

Comment: In the Chrome extesion the localhost file access live webservice.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this](http://fettig.net/weblog/2005/11/28/how-to-make-xmlhttprequest-connections-to-another-server-in-your-domain/) might solve your problem.